A question about Paley graphs
It is easy to prove that the Paley graph $QR(n)$ on $n$ vertices is a circulant graph when $n$ is prime. Computational evidence suggests that $QR(n)$ is not a circulant graph when $n$ is not a prime, but so far I have failed to find a proof.
Can you provide a proof (or a counter-example)?

for those like me who don't know what such a graph is, see here
